# Appearance, Online accounts disappeared in System Settings in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity-dash, 13.10, appearance, system-settings, online-accounts

I was installing some apps and icons then I noticed that there were about 4 games installed, so I went to the Software Centre to remove them. Then I wanted to add my Facebook account to Online Accounts but Alas! It was disappeared. But it was there when I searched for Online Accounts in the Unity Dash.

Please help me. I think I might have uninstalled the wrong packages. Can anyone tell me the packages that are associated with them?

Below are screenshots of my settings window and the Online Accounts icon in the Unity Dash.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0YcV.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKnrq.png]

Comment: The same issue I also have on my Ubuntu 13.10 after an upgrade.

Comment: What's happen if you run this command in terminal: `gnome-control-center credentials`?

Comment: It seems that this issue is only in Unity, because in Gnome-Shell (Gnome 3.8) it's OK.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution for me was to install that specific package that was missing:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity
```

Comment: this fixes it in 14.4

Comment: installing unity-control-center-signon did the trick for me. I wasn't able to see online accounts in the search as well as the settings menu.

Comment: Of the two, "unity-control-center" is best given the specific problem originally raised.  "gnome-control-center" less comprehensive, but still helpful for other needs.

Comment: Fixes in 16.10.

Answer (score 4):

Try to reinstall `gnome-control-center` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have added the gnome3 ppa in my ubuntu 13.10 for the sake of installing gnome desktop environment but after adding the ppa I changed my mind so I removed it. But before removing it I ran a update, so I think the gnome 3 ppa replaced the online acoounts, appearance, etc etc apps and so I installed synaptic. Go to the gnome-control-center and mark for complete removal and then applied the changes then I installed the gnome-control-center through synaptic and voila it worked. The problem was solved.

But this method a little bit dangerous. Can any expert have a eye on this.

Comment: That's exactly the same with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center`.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu but this answer is a *purge* of gnome control center, not just a normal reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

You might have accidentally uninstalled the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package.

Reinstall it with the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop`?!? That's `gnome-control-center` for sure.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu so what if it is (please elaborate)? It is possible the `ubuntu-desktop` package was uninstalled and this would fix it.

Comment: If `ubuntu-desktop` would have been removed, those images from the question would have looked completely different. You can try if you are curious. See also https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

ubuntu 13.10 doesnt work correctly with gnome 3.8