# Missing icons in System Settings

Tags: 13.10, system-settings, ubuntu-tweak

This a screenshot of [my System Settings window](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1466095_679658618720609_1786860340_n.jpg). As you can see I am missing the icons for: "Appearance","Online Accounts", "Security & Privacy", and "Time & Date". How can I restore them?

For comparison this is a screenshot of [the default Systems Settings window in Ubuntu 13.10](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Ubuntu-13-10-Saucy-Salamander-Screenshot-Tour-392149-8.jpg?1382014939).

Comment: Try the following link, the question is very similar...

http://askubuntu.com/questions/361885/appearance-online-accounts-disappeared-in-system-settings-in-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 2):

Try installing (or reinstalling) the package `ubuntu-desktop` by:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```